# Efficient ways of tracking updates to the database row

Tags: database

Given the following two tables, what are some of the most efficient ways to track updates to a given entity (Entity table) and its data (EntityData).

**Entity** { 
    EntityID: Num 
    EntityData: Blob 
}

**EntityData** { 
ID: Num 
EntityID: Num 
Prop: String 
Value: String 
Type: Num 
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Do you think trigger's is the way to go if the read/write (80/20) load is very high on the database with millions of records?

Comment: It would of course slow down your application but I think it will still be faster than do the tracking in for example PHP.